# Creating white space in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: Please see the image]

I'd like the body text to also fill the available white space next to the heading text as shown in the image.

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know

```css
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  column-count: 3;
  text-align: justify;
  column-gap: 20px;
  column-rule-color: green;
  column-rule-style: solid;
  column-rule-width: 10px;
}

h2 {
  column-span: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <h2>
    Inspired by the Traditions of Africa<br> BUt Ruled by a Contemporary Spirit
  </h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `<br>` in your heading (`h2`)? It's breaking the line. Remove that, and you'll get your desired output.

Comment: I'd like to fill in the blank with the text at the bottom, not the title.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to float the heading to the left, while having the body text wrap around it while also having 3 columns.

Answer (score 3):

From your answers, the following is a responsive solution I came up with. If you need spaces between paragraphs just wrap each paragraph in `p` tag. (You can check the responsiveness by running and checking the snippet in fullpage).

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .column {
    -moz-column-width: 30vw;
    column-width: 30vw;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-rule-color: green;
    column-rule-style: solid;
    column-rule-width: 10px;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .column {
      -moz-column-width: 47vw;
      column-width: 47vw;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .column {
      -moz-column-width: 100vw;
      column-width: 100vw;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="column">

  <h2>Inspired by the Traditions of Africa
    BUt Ruled by a Contemporary Spirit</h2>

  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

  It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code; `text-align: left;` in `h2` as shown below.

You can also try with adding `margin-right: 50%;` in `h2` as well.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .column {
    display: inline-block;
    column-count: 3;
    text-align: justify;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-rule-color: green;
    column-rule-style: solid;
    column-rule-width: 10px;
  }
  
  h2 {
    column-span: all;
    /* add this line */
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <h2>
    Inspired by the Traditions of Africa <br> BUt Ruled by a Contemporary Spirit
  </h2>
  <div class="column">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution

```css
 .column {
    display: grid;
    text-align: justify;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas: "header sidebar"
      "main sidebar";
  }

  h2 {
    grid-area: header;
  }

  p:first-of-type {
    grid-area: main;
  }

  p:nth-of-type(2n) {
    grid-area: sidebar;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Inspired by the Traditions of Africa But Ruled by a Contemporary Spirit</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>

    <p>
      It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

for this problem is by removing `column-span: all;` from the `<h2>`, because the only values you can have for `column-span` are `all` and `none`. You can use css grid to achieve a similar idea too

```css
 .column {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-rule-color: green;
    column-rule-style: solid;
    column-rule-width: 10px;
  }
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="column">
    <h2>Inspired by the Traditions of Africa
      BUt Ruled by a Contemporary Spirit</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
  </div>
</body>
```